# Controlling a webbrowser without c# webbrowser control

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, browser, bots

I want to be able to launch multiple browser windows and get the html from them and interact with them like I can with the .net web browser control. The problem is the c# web browser control requires STA threading and that makes my program slower and error prone. Is their a way I can talk to the real IE browser or even Chrome, Firefox etc and do this?

I know there is paid third party solutions and stuff but I was wondering if anybody knew of any free libraries that are reliable and work. I can't use HttpWebRequest for what I am doing, so don't suggest that please.

I will be running on Windows and using C#.

Comment: WebKit.NEt is a good starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Awesomeium](http://awesomium.codeplex.com/) is a Webkit/Chromium (Chrome) based browser you can talk to via a .NET wrapper, much like the WebBrowser control. I'm not sure on the STA threading requirement though.

As for STA Threading making your application "slower and error prone" -- This sounds odd, perhaps you should investigate solving this.

Comment: How can I fill in form fields and click a submit button with this control? With .net IE browser I can say element.SetAttribute() and element.InvokeMember('click'). What is equivalent of this in this sdk?

Comment: I've never attempted it myself, but according to the documentation you can execute arbitrary [Javascript](http://awesomium.com/docs/1_6_4/sharp_api/html/0cb62099-bd17-342a-d988-be8302d611c2.htm) methods, this would allow you to interact with the page. You can also set callbacks from Javascript to allow JS to notify you asynchronously. I'm not 100% sure you can directly access the DOM in C# though, you may have to do that in JS.

Comment: Yea that is what I found too. I;m still unsure if I will use this SDK but I will give you points because it looks like a good library.

Answer (score 2):

I have used WebKit.NET. Its free and works great (supports flash, css, renders correctly, has a javascript engine). It may or may not be to extensive for what you are doing.

http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/

There are plenty of guides, and the demo has a fully featured tab system.

EDIT: I was fooling around with it, and made an enhanced version of the demo

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For IE (only). Free:
Microsoft Internet Controls

```
using SHDocVw;
```

Microsoft HTML Object Library

```
using mshtml;
```

With these you can do things like

```
foreach (InternetExplorer brIns in _allWindows)
            {
                var htmlDoc = brIns.Document as HTMLDocument;
                if (htmlDoc != null && htmlDoc.all.item(elementName) != null)
                {
                    var elem = htmlDoc.all.item(elementName) as HTMLInputElement;
                    if (elem != null && attributeName == null)
                    {
                        _ieCurrentDoc = htmlDoc;
                        _currentHtml = htmlDoc.documentElement.outerHTML;
                        return true;
                    }
                    if (elem != null && elem.getAttribute(attributeName) != null)
                    {
                        _ieCurrentDoc = htmlDoc;
                        _currentHtml = htmlDoc.documentElement.outerHTML;
                        return true;
                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: This is using the same activex underneath and requires STA it seems.

Answer (score 1):

Or another webbrowser control: http://code.google.com/p/geckofx/

[Embeding Firefox Brower In C# Using GeckoFX](http://winform-net.blogspot.com.au/2011/05/embeding-firefox-brower-gecko-engine-in.html)

Comment: Geckofx requires STA (if you don't want it to crash at least)

Comment: Also the geckofx version in link only works with a very old firefox version. here's a link to a newer version. https://bitbucket.org/geckofx/geckofx-13.0/downloads